# Intellij plugin api method forcePsiPostprocessAndRestoreElement purpose

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to modify plugin so that it supports older version of IDEA (IC-129). One of the problems I've faced is that it uses `forcePsiPostprocessAndRestoreElement` from `CodeInsightUtilCore` class which does not exist in older sdk. After reading [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/13.0.0/com/intellij/codeInsight/CodeInsightUtilCore.java) I still don't understand what this method is doing. Can someone explain to it's meaning or(and) point to the old way of doing same thing?

Comment: `CodeInsightUtilBase#forcePsiPostprocessAndRestoreElement` https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/6ef6b5fe04c67c3e5188667849c76b5240aac3b6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When modifying PSI, formatting is applied at the end of a write action or at the explicit call of doPostponedOperationsAndUnblockDocument. This call may be necessary if you need to modify the document, otherwise you'll get an assertion that PSI modification is not yet complete (formatting is missing). Since formatting will change the document and PSI, PsiElement that you have might get invalidated, or at least its range will likely be changed.

forcePsiPostprocessAndRestoreElement performs the postponed formatting immediately and tries to find in the updated tree a PsiElement corresponding to the one you've held before, that you might need for further processing.

Alternatively, you can create SmartPsiElementPointer to that element and hope it will survive formatter modifications (usually it will).

Comment: There is a method `fastenBelts` in `SmartPointerManagerImpl`. Is this a joke? How could one even hope to learn api like this? I googled and found nothing on PsiElement lifecycle. That's really frustrating.

Comment: This method name is a joke, but it isn't API so you don't need to understand that. Sorry that the API is so under-documented. BTW contributions, including javadoc, are very welcome.

Comment: Is there 'entry-point' class (package) where I should begin to understand the whole picture? And is there a place (like git submit comments) where justifications of API evolution were put?

Comment: For different API parts, entry points are different. I'd recommend reading architectural overview and other topics at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment. Git commit messages (https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) might shed light on API evolution, at least since 2005, but most likely reading them will be a waste of time. The best place to ask questions is the plugin development forum (http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development)